# Error: "image 'en/FSharp.Core.resources.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed / condition `idx < t->rows' not met"

Tags: xamarin, f#, xamarin.android, mono, suave

I'm unable to found why my app is crashing. I have a weird error **condition `idx < t->rows' not met"**.

This is activated when try to execute a embebed web server (Suave):

```
let startServer() =
    **startWebServerAsync defaultConfig app <--- HERE**
    |> snd
    |> Async.StartAsTask 
    |> ignore
```

However, this work when run in iOS. I reinstall everything and yet it fail.

```
> am start -n "com.elmalabarista.Sales/md537c0d4a6026eb296b9b34627c676feee.MainActivity"
> Starting: Intent { cmp=com.elmalabarista.Sales/md537c0d4a6026eb296b9b34627c676feee.MainActivity }

Loaded assembly: Sales.Droid.dll
Loaded assembly: Bogus.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Core.dll
Loaded assembly: FormsViewGroup.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: FSharp.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Npgsql.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Serilog.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Serilog.Sinks.Console.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Serilog.Sinks.File.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Suave.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xam.Plugin.WebView.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xam.Plugin.WebView.Droid.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.FSharp.ResourceProvider.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Java.Interop.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Collections.Concurrent.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Primitives.dll [External]
[zygote] Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
[zygote] Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
[zygote] Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
[zygote] Debugger is no longer active
[monodroid] Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.elmalabarista.Sales/files/.__override__`
[monodroid] Using override path: /data/user/0/com.elmalabarista.Sales/files/.__override__
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/com.elmalabarista.Sales/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.elmalabarista.Sales/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/../legacy/Android/data/com.elmalabarista.Sales/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/com.elmalabarista.Sales-VPQSGydqU-zpqC-2Ntc5_Q==/lib/x86/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/com.elmalabarista.Sales/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=10.0.2.2:50168,embedding=1
[Mono] Image addref mscorlib[0xa32dbf40] -> mscorlib.dll[0xac48be00]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'mscorlib' (mscorlib.dll)
[Mono] AOT: image 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.elmalabarista.Sales-VPQSGydqU-zpqC-2Ntc5_Q==/lib/x86/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.elmalabarista.Sales-VPQSGydqU-zpqC-2Ntc5_Q==/lib/x86/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
[Mono] Assembly mscorlib[0xa32dbf40] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] Image addref Sales.Droid[0xa32a4120] -> Sales.Droid.dll[0xac48c800]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'Sales.Droid' (Sales.Droid.dll)
[Mono] Assembly Sales.Droid[0xa32a4120] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'Sales.Droid.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.elmalabarista.Sales-VPQSGydqU-zpqC-2Ntc5_Q==/lib/x86/libaot-Sales.Droid.dll.so" not found
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Sales.Droid.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.elmalabarista.Sales-VPQSGydqU-zpqC-2Ntc5_Q==/lib/x86/libaot-Sales.Droid.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'Sales.Droid.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/Sales.Droid/Sales.Droid.config'.
[Mono] Image addref Bogus[0xa32a40c0] -> Bogus.dll[0xac48d200]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'Bogus' (Bogus.dll)
[Mono] Assembly Bogus[0xa32a40c0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'Bogus.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.elmalabarista.Sales-VPQSGydqU-zpqC-2Ntc5_Q==/lib/x86/libaot-Bogus.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Bogus.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.elmalabarista.Sales-VPQSGydqU-zpqC-2Ntc5_Q==/lib/x86/libaot-Bogus.dll.so" not found
......
......
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xam.Plugin.WebView.Abstractions[0xa32a4780] -> System.Threading.Tasks[0x8a5b35c0]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Threading.Tasks[0x8a5b35c0] -> mscorlib[0xa32dbf40]: 53
Loaded assembly: System.Threading.Tasks.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref FSharp.Core[0xa32a4180] -> System.Threading.Tasks[0x8a5b35c0]: 3
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/FSharp.Core.resources/4.4.3.0_en-us_b03f5f7f11d50a3a/FSharp.Core.resources.dll'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/FSharp.Core.resources.dll'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/FSharp.Core.resources/4.4.3.0_en-us_b03f5f7f11d50a3a/FSharp.Core.resources.exe'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/FSharp.Core.resources.exe'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: 'en-US/FSharp.Core.resources.dll'.
[Mono] Image addref FSharp.Core.resources[0x8a5b4040] -> en/FSharp.Core.resources.dll[0x8a667100]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'FSharp.Core.resources' (en/FSharp.Core.resources.dll)
[Mono] Assembly FSharp.Core.resources[0x8a5b4040] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'en/FSharp.Core.resources.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.elmalabarista.Sales-VPQSGydqU-zpqC-2Ntc5_Q==/lib/x86/libaot-FSharp.Core.resources.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/FSharp.Core.resources.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.elmalabarista.Sales-VPQSGydqU-zpqC-2Ntc5_Q==/lib/x86/libaot-FSharp.Core.resources.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'en/FSharp.Core.resources.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/FSharp.Core.resources/FSharp.Core.resources.config'.
Loaded assembly: en/FSharp.Core.resources.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref FSharp.Core[0xa32a4180] -> System.Linq[0xa32a5a40]: 3
[] * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-7/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/metadata/metadata.c:1117, **condition `idx < t->rows' not met**
[libc] Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4310 (labarista.Sales), pid 4310 (labarista.Sales)
```

This are my versions:

> Version 7.5.2 (build 40) Installation UUID:
>   8eb9f5aa-ff7e-48bd-b658-76b0bff55ddc Runtime:     Mono 5.10.1.57
>   (2017-12/ea8a24b1bbf) (64-bit)    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
>     Xamarin.Mac 4.4.1.178 (master / eeaeb7e6)
>
> Package version: 510010057
>
> NuGet Version: 4.3.1.4445
>
> .NET Core Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet Runtime Version:
>   2.0.5 SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.4/Sdks SDK Version: 2.1.4 MSBuild SDKs:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.10.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks
>
> Xamarin.Profiler Version: 1.6.2 Location: /Applications/Xamarin
>   Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler
>
> Apple Developer Tools Xcode 9.2 (13772) Build 9C40b
>
> Xamarin.Mac Version: 4.4.1.193 (Visual Studio Community)
>
> Xamarin.iOS Version: 11.12.0.4 (Visual Studio Community) Hash:
>   64fece5f Branch: d15-7 Build date: 2018-05-29 20:00:44-0400
>
> Xamarin.Android Version: 8.3.3.2 (Visual Studio Community)    Supported
>   Android versions:
>         8.1 (API level 27)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1 SDK Platform Tools Version: 28.0.0 SDK Build
>   Tools Version: 27.0.3
>
> Java SDK: /usr java version "1.8.0_131" Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
>
> Build Information Release ID: 705020040 Git revision:
>   cfe2fc0566bc4db990242959de40505a13f58352 Build date: 2018-05-30
>   11:24:18-04 Xamarin addins: 3ac7413ef51a88e06367313c27aec8f7292752a6
>   Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-7
>
> Operating System Mac OS X 10.12.6 Darwin 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version
>   16.7.0
>       Tue Jan 30 11:27:06 PST 2018
>       root:xnu-3789.73.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

P.D: Weirdly, it only happened in the emulator. In a real device it not crash.

Comment: The error is being thrown from Mono for failing an assert:  https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/a49a68c6d7a48aabd4f24a38bbc93d18e02dd2ca/mono/metadata/metadata.c#L1117
I would file this issue against the Xamarin-android repository here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues
It would help if you could provide a small test project that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Actually I realized you should file this against the Suave library, but I see you already did: https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/issues/698

Comment: it's not a suave bug, it's a mono bug